# What classroom course should I take for the MCTS: SharePoint 2010, Configuration certification?

Tags: exams, exam

I am required to obtain my MCTS: SharePoint 2010, Configuration cert. What classroom course(s) should I attend to help me pass the exam?

Any other tips or pointers in preparation for the exam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a training plan from Microsoft which gives you a nice idea about the different phases you need to explore while preparing for the certification -
http://learning.microsoft.com/manager/LearningPlanV2.aspx?resourceId=9173b319-2607-4954-9418-010059016602&clang=en-US&cats=d4e8e42c-3d5a-4a6e-915d-d99556a49bd7&locale=en-US

You get a whole bunch of information from the official site like, Overview of the exam, how the skills are being measured for the certification, etc. - http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-667&Locale=en-us#tab2

There are also official 5 days classroom training available as 2 batches - http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Exam.aspx?ID=70-667&Locale=en-us#tab3

The site also helps you in receiving sample questions and practice tests to make yourself well prepared for the exam.

Good Luck with your exams !!!

Answer (score 2):

The book - [MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-667): Configuring Microsoft® SharePoint® 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?id=14586&locale=en-us) is quite helpful not just for the exam but as graded lessons in sequence for understanding SharePoint administration.

Good luck with the exam.

Answer (score 1):

If your are doing sharePoint administrative work on a daily basis and try to keep up with the features the product delivers from blogs and other tubes in the internet there is a good chance of passing the exam. I did it this way. If i had failed i would grab some brain dumps. The most important element is that you not only get the answer to the question but also the reason, why it is right and even better i had found some brain dumps explaining why the wrong answers are wrong (this was way back in the .net 2.0 certification i had done).

My boss ordered brain dumps from Testking but the way they deliver and the quality of the material (no info on why the answer ist right) is more than questionable. A friend of mine directed me to this site:

http://www.examcollection.com/